# Redirecting process output in Task Spooler

Tags: bash, pipe, task-scheduler

I am running processes of the form

```
command --with arguments > logfile
```

and would now dispatch those via task-spooler, so I tried

```
tsp command --with arguments > logfile
```

but the logfile contains the task id from `tsp`, not my process output. I also tried

```
tsp "command --with arguments > logfile"
```

which didn't work at all (`tsp` claims it can't execute the command).

Any ideas how to make the process output redirection part of the process being dispatched to the task spooler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this without having to run `bash` separately by escaping the `>` character using a backslash (`\>`):

```
tsp command --with arguments \> logfile
```

Answer (score 4):

With a little bit of digging, this [Google Groups Post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/taskspooler/qCInvPUwABQ) notes a simple solution:

```
tsp bash -c "command -with arguments > logfile"
```